# Read multiple PDB files using R language?

Tags: r, pdb

R language uses `read.pdb` file for individual protein.

```
p= read.pdb(D:/R/1XYZ.pdb)
```

I want R to read multiple pdb files from folder and then store it. Is there any code for it?

Comment: Make your question a bit more informative.

Answer (score 3):

If you want to store your files in a variable, the following may help you. The `list.files`function used below can also take a 'path' parameter if you are not running R in the folder of your .pdb files.

```
pdbfiles <- list.files(pattern="*.pdb", full.names=TRUE) # Rerieving .pdb files
pdb <- lapply(pdbfiles, read.pdb) # Apply the 'read.pdb' function on each file
```

I hope it helps you.

Answer (score 0):

Just to add a `tidyverse` answer:

```
library(tidyverse)

df <- list.files(pattern = ".pdb") %>%
  map(read.pdb) %>% 
  bind_rows()
```

Answer (score 0):

You also can do that:

```
## load libraries
library(tidyverse)

## list files
files <- list.files(pattern = '.pdb')

## read files
df <- do.call(bind_rows, purrr::map(files, read.pdb, .progress = TRUE))
```